# Unit testing a partial text searching service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm trying to unit test a search function I have that will match a partially entered string to a result if one exists. 
My failing test:

```
    [Theory(DisplayName = "Retrieve a Customer by partial name if the customer exists.")]
    [InlineData("fifth")]
    public async Task ProviderClass_GetCustomersByPartialName(string name)
    {
        var mockISecurityTokenProvider = new Mock<ISecurityTokenProvider>();
        mockISecurityTokenProvider.Setup(i => i.GetSecurityToken()).Returns(() => new SecurityToken
        {
            CurrentAccessLevel = AccessLevel.Full
        });

        var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(_context, mockISecurityTokenProvider.Object);
        var irrelevantRepo = new irrelevantRepo(_context, mockISecurityTokenProvider.Object);

        var service = new CustomerProvider(customerRepository, irrelevantRepo,
            new CustomerFactory(), 
            new Mock<IGenericModelFactory<mockedModel, mockedTable>>().Object,
            new Mock<IGenericModelFactory<mockedModel, mockedTable>>().Object,
            new Mock<IGenericModelFactory<mockedModel, mockedTable>>().Object, 
            new Mock<IGenericModelFactory<mockedModel, mockedTable>>().Object,
            new Mock<IGenericModelFactory<mockedModel, mockedTable>>().Object);

        var item = await service.GetCustomersByPartialNameAsync(name);

        Assert.True(item?.Any(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())));
```

And the service code I am testing:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomersByPartialNameAsync(string name,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var items =
            await _customerReader.GetCustomers()
                //Includes of tables where relevant results might be
                .Where(i => i.CustomerStatusId == 1 && i.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return items.Select(Create);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. The only mock-setup you should use (and I can't see) it should be `customerReader.GetCustomers()`
2. Please use `default(CancellationToken)` or `CancellationToken.None`
3. Please mock only when necessary, consider using a fake

Hope this help